# Error when running simpleITK cannot detect ImageJ or FIJI despite FIJI.app being in my user folder

Tags: python, imagej, itk

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt15E.png)

Hello,
I Keep encountering this issue when using simpleitk despite having Fiji.app in my Users folder
C:\Users[user]\Fiji.app
I am trying to generate an image using simpleitk. I am using Jupytyr Notebooks and installed the following pips.
python -m pip install itk-elastix
python -m pip install itk
python -m pip install simpleitk
python -m pip install itkwidgets

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly.
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you call the Show function with the debugOn set to True, what is the output?  It should print out the directories that it searches for Fiji in.

Comment: Also, you can set the SITK_SHOW_COMMAND environment variable to the full path of the Fiji executable. On Windows that's the ImageJ-win64.exe within the Fiji.app directory.